# Sporadic 502 error with gwt rpc calls

Tags: gwt, rpc

I have a GWT application that is giving sporadic 502 errors all of a sudden. I have managed to replicate it by opening multiple connections to the application. Eventually I get a 502 error and the response headers for look as follows:

```
Server: squid/2.6.STABLE5
Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2011 12:08:03 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1014
Expires: Fri, 19 Aug 2011 12:08:03 GMT
X-Squid-Error: ERR_ZERO_SIZE_OBJECT 0
X-Cache: MISS from sentinel.bsgza.bsg.co.za
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sentinel.bsgza.bsg.co.za:3128
Via: 1.0 sentinel.bsgza.bsg.co.za:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE5)
Connection: close
```

The response headers for the successful rpc calls look like this:

```
Date: Fri, 19 Aug 2011 13:04:37 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Length: 249
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-Cache: MISS from sentinel.bsgza.bsg.co.za
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sentinel.bsgza.bsg.co.za:3128
Via: 1.0 sentinel.bsgza.bsg.co.za:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE5)
Connection: keep-alive
```

We have been able to repeat this on a local server too so it is not a network issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to route your RPC call via a proxy (Squid). Or at least try to configure Squid to not try to cache them, but only to forward.

**Update**

It's suggested [here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/786517) that such condition might occur with HTTP POST (used by GWT-RPC) by clients behind PPPoA gateways (cable modems) which have wrong MTU set. Do you see this errors from such clients?